# Circle of radius 1 is inscribed in an equilateral triangle PQR. The point of contacts of C with PQ, QR, RP are D,E,F....

Tags: circles

> Circle of radius 1 is inscribed in an equilateral triangle PQR. The point of contacts of C with PQ, QR, RP are D,E,F respectively. If PQ is $\sqrt 3 x + y-6=0$ and D is $(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} , \frac 32)$ and origin and centre of the C are on the same side, find equation of C

Now according to the answer, the center of the given circle is $(\sqrt 3,1)$

Let the center be $(h,k)$

Then
$$-\sqrt 3 \times \frac{k-\frac 32}{h-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}}=-1$$
But the answer doesn’t seem to satisfying $(h,k)$ in this equation.

I feel like this question will end up embarrassing me for being too simple, but I really don’t know why this formula is not working

Comment: Could you confirm whether the equation and point are correct, as the point D does not satisfy the equation for PQ, but it lies on it.

Comment: Given a single edge and a single inscribed point there are two circles tangent to the inscribed point and hence two configurations which solve the problem. In other words the solution is not unique. This is resolved if the orientation of the letters on the triangle reflects a clockwise or anticlockwise positioning though. This could be the source of your confusion.

Comment: @user812951 yeah I noticed that too, but the values are all correct. In fact, if you google this question, you will see lot of websites solving it

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the point $D$ is definitively not on $PQ$, we will "slightly change" the statement, so that the expected answer is an answer, according to the following picture:

[image: math stackexchange 4014899 analytic geometry problem]

> **Problem:**
> $\Delta PQR$ is an equilateral triangle with points in the cartesian plane $\Bbb R^2$, so that the equation of the line $PQ$ is $\sqrt 3 x +y-6=0$. The incircle $\odot (I)$ of $\Delta PQR$ touches the sides of this triangle opposite to $P,Q,R$ in $D,E,F$ respectively.
> The point $D$ has coordinates $\displaystyle\left(\frac {\sqrt 3}2,\frac 32\right)$.

> Find the equation of the incircle $\odot(I)=\odot(DEF)$.

---

**Note:** I could not understand the "same side" story.

**Note:**
I am against formulations of the shape <<*If $PQ$ is ... and $D$ is ... and ... find equation of the circle $\odot(I)$*>>

Why? Since this "if-then sentence" is not giving anything, it is an implication. Even if we understand the if-condition, and would be polite to assume it, it would be false to solve the problem till we can show that the assumption is true. But we do not have enough information to decide. I would not recommend to do this in an exam, as i did, except for the case of an ultima ratio. Well, i had luck, the professor accepted my logic.

---

**Solution:**
Since $\Delta PQR$ is equilateral, the triangle $\Delta DEF$ is also equilateral.
Its circumcircle $\odot(I)$ has radius $1$, so the two sides of equal length $1$ in $\Delta IDF$ are building an angle of $120^\circ$, which gives
$$
DF^2=1^2+1^2-2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot \cos 120^\circ 
=1+1+1=3\ .
$$
So $F\in PQ$ is a point on the line $PQ$ with known equation, at known distance $\sqrt 3$ from the known point $D$. Very quickly the "two chances for $F$", let us denote them by $F_1$ and $F_2$ are
$$
F_1 =
\left(
\frac{3\sqrt 3}2,\frac 32
\right) \ ,
\qquad
F_2=(\sqrt 3,3)\ .
$$
We consider the two chances separately.

- For $F=F_1$, since the point $Q$ makes $\Delta DFQ$ equilateral, and $Q$ satisfies the given equation of $PQ$, we have only the chance $Q=F_2$. The homothety centered in $Q$ and factor $2$ brings $\Delta QDF$ into $\Delta QRP$, so the other two vertices of the latter are $R(0,0)$ and $P(2\sqrt 3,0)$. The mid point of $PR$ is thus $E=(\sqrt 3,0)$. (Or we could compute $E$ as the reflection of $Q$ in $DF$.) The median $QE$ between $Q(\sqrt3,3)$ and $E(\sqrt 3,0)$ has length $3$, and contains the point $I$, which is also the centroid, placed at distances in proportion $2:1$ from $Q$ and $E$, so
  $$
  I=(\sqrt 3,1)\ .
  $$
  (Well, this point and the origin both satisfy $\sqrt 3 x +y-6<0$, so they are on the same side of $PQ$, but the next point has the same property.)

It remains to write down the equation of the circle centered in this point $I$ having radius one, $(x-\sqrt 3)^2+(y-1)^2=1^2$.

- For $F=F_2$, with the same argument, $Q$ is the other "$F$-choice", $Q=F_1$, and we construct similarly $I$. The reflection of $Q$ w.r.t. $DF$ is the point $E(0,3)$, so the second choice of $I$ is $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}2,\frac 52\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the writers of this question confused the order while naming the line segments and that's the main problem. Clearly, $D$ is not on $PQ$ as the question states:

```
The point of contacts of C with PQ, QR, RP are D,E,F respectively.
```

See the diagram and it will be more clear.

[image]

Comment: Another good point. Not exactly an answer though more of a comment.

Comment: OP was asking for the reason why their equation didn't work; I didn't think they wanted a full solution of the problem.

Comment: True. I've gotten into the habit of just putting a comment when I don't give a full answer since many times the asker will edit the question when given a quick counterexample especially when it could be a minor thing in the statement.

Comment: The question does in fact use ‘respectively’, I forgot to include it in. There are plenty of solutions online that seem to solve it effortlessly, but I don’t how since the question is so fundamentally incorrect. I will link them you want

Comment: Perhaps you are right about my answer being like a comment, but I think the writers of this question confused the order while naming the line segments and that's the main problem.